# Why does my resolv.conf file get regenerated every time?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

My `/etc/resolv.conf` file gets regenerated every time, making me loose Google DNS servers when I reconnect my 3G modem.

For changing the DNS settings, I looked at http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html.

My `dhclient.conf` is pretty big (58 lines), so I posted it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/858v8L3m).

However, here is the entire `dhclient.conf` without comment lines or blank lines:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
send host-name "<hostname>";
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

I am using `wvdial` instead of Network Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about `wvdial` .  At this point I suspect it or another package not yet discovered is involved here.  Do you know if you've installed other network-related applications or tools that might be touching DNS, DHCP, interfaces, etc. in some fashion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DNS server configuration always be changed automatically](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27358/dns-server-configuration-always-be-changed-automatically)

Answer (score 6):

In 12.04, resolvconf is installed by default. Here is a quick summary of how to make DNS configuration changes for some common use cases:

For a static configuration using `ifup`, use `dns-nameservers` and `dns-search` entries in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

For a static configuration using `NetworkManager`, select the `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` `Method` and enter addresses and domain names in the `Additional DNS servers` and `Additional search domains` fields in the Connection Editor.

To override resolvconf's default configuration, use `base`, `head` and `tail` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/`. Only enter addresses and domain names in these files as a temporary measure, since they really belong elsewhere, as described above.

Disabling resolvconf is not recommended, but you can replace the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` with a regular file.

For more information, see Stéphane Graber's [blog post](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is to keep your Google DNS servers in resolv.conf, you can edit
`/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf` and add :

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4;
```

The only difference between what you have and what I'm showing here is that you've got both name-servers on a single line, per the docs you've mentioned.

Unless I'm missing something, your dhclient.conf is not a problem here. 
At this point, I'm assuming that the issue has to do with wvdial.

Here's something to try, from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420718):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ppp/peers/wvdial
```

REMOVE parameter usepeerdns and save file.
Code:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

add these lines:

```
check DNS = no
auto DNS = no
```

Comment: @jgbelacqua i tried it in spearated lines but didnt work : P

Comment: @Jakh I'm assuming that moving the prepend lines closer to the top also fails?  (This is how I've got mine set up.)

Comment: @jgbelacqua yes i tried that too it does ;]

Comment: @Jakh -- have you tried editing the `request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;` line to remove name-servers there?

Comment: @jgbelacqu No ill try it now and let you kno

Comment: @jgbelacqu No its didnt work : [

Answer (score 4):

The best way to set a nameserver via the CLI, without NetworkManger, with a static address, or independent of the connection is this:

Install the [resolvconf](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/resolvconf) package.

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

(ignore the scary warning. /etc/resolv.conf is autogenerated, so the warning is there so it will get put in /etc/resolv.conf when /etc/resolv.conf is generated.) To the end of the file, add

```
 nameserver <ip_of_nameserver>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> and answer yes to saving the file. To finish up, regenerate /etc/resolv.conf so the changes are applied right now:

```
 sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: It should be added that it is generally not a good idea to put a static nameserver address in resolv.conf. Please read /usr/share/doc/resolvconf/README.gz.

Comment: Not working for me. The resolv.conf continues to get regenerated by wsl and overwrites the resolvconf settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `domain-name-servers` dhclient.conf option.

Comment: check his pastebin -- looks like he already has this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. By the way, your solution could be correct, so consider posting it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: hello @adam can youplease be more clear im  a noob : ] thank

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem with the following commands:

```
echo "nameserver 212.217.0.1" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
ln -s /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head /etc/resolv.conf
resolvconf -u
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: You may have resolved the problem this way, but it is an utter misconfiguration. You have ended up symlinking /etc/resolv.conf to a static file which happens to be one of resolvconf's configuration files. If you want to disable resolvconf then it would be much simpler just to delete the symlink /etc/resolv.conf and put a static file there.

Answer (score -1):

you propably have the packet resolvconf installed. in that case, whenever an interface comes up, the resolv.conf is updated.
you can add static entries using the /etc/resolv.conf.tail file, see the man page for resolv.conf for more.

Comment: noo i dont have that package installed

Comment: The resolvconf program updates /etc/resolv.conf, but only if /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf. The resolvconf package was introduced because so many *other* programs were stomping on /etc/resolv.conf independently of one another, resulting in chaos. Please read /usr/share/doc/resolvconf/README.gz. Thus from the fact that /etc/resolv.conf was updated, it does not follow (in March 2011 when the question was asked) that resolvconf was installed. More probably pppd was rewriting the file. (As of Ubuntu 12.04, however, resolvconf is part of the base system.)

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem, the DNS server that my mobile provider provides was rather poor so I wanted to use Google's DNS. Also NetworkManager does a really poor job of handling mobile broadband connections so `wvdial` is a necessity.

As it turns out the `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link in `ubuntu 12.10` and maybe even `12.04`. Here's what I've done
`sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf` after this you can create a new `resolv.conf` with `vim` or the editor of your choice and add google's nameservers or any other nameservers that you prefer. Save it and you're done.

If you're afraid of breaking something you can make a note of the existing symlink by doing a `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf` before `unlinking` it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment. If my answer is really bad advice I'll be happy to delete it. Please do let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks