# `nslookup` fails—but works if I specify the default DNS server. Isn't it the same?

Tags: dns

I have a broken Unity desktop and am trying to install compizconfig-settings-manager to sort things out. Unfortunately, `apt-get install` fails, giving me "Temporary failure: ca.archive.ubuntu.com" messages.

- `nslookup ca.archive.ubuntu.com` times out.
- My laptop is connected to the router via `eno1`; the default DNS server for that connection is my router at 192.168.1.1.
- `nslookup ca.archive.ubuntu.com 192.168.1.1` returns the expected result.

How can I fix DNS lookup on this machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Quick simple hack is to add the entry into `/etc/hosts` like so

   ```
   91.189.88.149    ca.archive.ubuntu.com
   ```

   But that should only be a temporary solution.
2. Fix your `resolv.conf` file:
   [Why does my resolv.conf file get regenerated every time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30942/why-does-my-resolv-conf-file-get-regenerated-every-time)
   and [How do I get resolvconf to regenerate resolv.conf after I change /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224966/how-do-i-get-resolvconf-to-regenerate-resolv-conf-after-i-change-etc-network-in?rq=1)

   When fixing your `resolv.conf` file, make sure that your router (local DNS server) is specified as the first one, then add a backup like google (8.8.8.8) or openDNS or comcast or your other favorite DNS provider.